# Change round window control buttons to square shape

Tags: gnome, metacity

Ubuntu 16.04 with Gnome Metacity
How can I:
1) Change the shape of the window control buttons to square?
2) Change the color of the window control buttons?
3) Change the color of the highlighted areas, sliders, etc.?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

A good way to get any level of customization is with themes. This includes changing the way the window control buttons look, etc.

A good list of themes can be found here [NoobsLab Collection](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/themes?field.series_filter=utopic)

Answer (score 0):

Open Nautilus

```
sudo nautilus
```

and go to the

```
/usr/share/themes/YOUR_CURRENT_THEME
```

find gtk3 file and open it.

1. Search `outline-radius` and change value to the 0. you may have multiple outline-radius in your gtk3 file.
2. I don't know what is your current theme, but you can search `.button` class and tweak the color.
3. For slider color: it has many classes. for example for scale slider you can simply search `.scale.slider` and change the color.

   For highlight color. Every theme defined const for these type of colors. You can search `@define-color` and after that see which one has `highlight` in it  and change it to whatever you want.

   You have also another option for changing the highlight color. Open Ubuntu Software and install `theme configuration` (Sometimes Logout and Login needed to see the change).

After each change you must load theme again. For that, you need [gnome tweak tool](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gnome-tweak-tool/)

If you need a color tool, Install [Gpick](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gpick/)